# How to connect pika to rabbitMQ remote server? (python, pika)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

In my local machine I can have:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
```

for both scripts (send.py and recv.py) in order to establish proper communication, but what about to establish communication from 12.23.45.67 to 132.45.23.14 ? I know about all the parameters that ConnectionParameters() take but I am not sure what to pass to the host or what to pass to the client. It would be appreciated if someone could give an example for host scrip and client script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/parameters.html, where it says `'rabbit-server1'` you should enter the remote host name of the IP.

Be aware that the `guest` account can only connect via localhost https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: could you please give an example for the host scrip and another one for the client script, at least the connection part. This helped me understand how it woks but doesn't really explain the specifics of the connection.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your help, it did led me to the solution. As the second link says, the rabbitmq.config file needs to be modified and then restart the server in order to accept remote hosts in the 'guest' user of rabbitmq

Answer (score 41):

first step is to add another account to your rabbitMQ server. To do this in windows...

1. open a command prompt window (windows key->cmd->enter)
2. navigate to the "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.2\sbin" directory ( type "cd \Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.2\sbin" and press enter )
3. enable management plugin (type "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management" and press enter)
4. open a broswer window to the management console & navigate to the admin section (http://localhost:15672/#/users with credentials "guest" - "guest")
5. add a new user (for example "the_user" with password "the_pass"
6. give that user permission to virtual host "/" (click user's name then click "set permission")

Now if you modify the connection info as done in the following modification of send.py you should find success:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('the_user', 'the_pass')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('132.45.23.14',
                                   5672,
                                   '/',
                                   credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body='Hello W0rld!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

Hope this helps